# Trim URL to Root

Tags: delphi

How can this be done in Delphi? For example..

URL = https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm#inbox

Trimed URL = https://mail.google.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example code using Indy's `TIdURI` might be:

```
uses
  IdURI;

function GetProtoAndHost(const URI: string): string;
var
  IdURI: TIdURI;
begin
  IdURI := TIdURI.Create(URI);
  try
    Result := IdURI.Protocol + '://' + IdURI.Host + '/';
  finally
    IdURI.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Can this be combined with this?

uri := TIdURI.Create(GetProtoAndHost(document.url));

try
 IdCookieManager1.AddServerCookies(cookies,uri);

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting there. I personally don't know about cookies and Indy.

Comment: i mean to pass a url root to the AddServerCookies without double creating TidURI

Comment: OK, in that case I would simply blank out all the other properties of `TIdURI`, i.e. Document, UserName, Password, Port etc.

Comment: Cookies are tied to the complete URL that sends them.  You should NOT be reducing the URL to just its root hostname by itself. The path information is important and should not be stripped off.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well for Gmail cookie is stored under trimed url NOT the full one.

Comment: I assure you, cookies are always associated with the full URI that sent them, otherwise the cookie's `Path` attribute cannot be validated properly.  A cookie with a `Path` attribute cannot be sent back to a URI that does not match the `Path`, that would be a security violation.  Web browsers enforce that.  `TIdCookieManager` enforces that.

Answer (score 4):

```
Function GetRoot(const Path:String):String;
var
 i:Integer;
begin
  i := Pos('//',Path);
  if i>0 then
      i := PosEx('/',Path,i+2)
  else i := Pos('/',Path);
  if i=0 then i := Length(Path);

  Result := Copy(Path,1,i);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `TIdURI` class (in the `IdURI' unit) from Indy.  It's a URI/URL parser.  You feed it a URL, and it parses it out into the various components.  Play around with it and see how it works.  Your particular question could be answered by looking at the Host and Protocol properties once it's parsed the URL.